# Redirect output from background process

Tags: bash, shell-script, io-redirection

Objective: Have program running in the background (with a PID), capture the PID, collect output and kill PID.

My code:

```
tee -a log | program | tee -a log &
PID=$!
disown $PID
sleep 10
pkill '^program*' 2> /dev/null
```

I ran a variation of different redirect options but I can't seem to have the output being sent to "log".

I've also tried an approach mentioned in a another thread, that recommended the usage of:

```
program &> log &
```

Even though that runs fine, it can't seem to capture the output of "program".

"program" is also interactive in a way that it will, for some seconds, output commands, that's why I have the sleep 10 to give it enough time to finish.

Any tips?

Thank you!

Comment: if `program &> file` doesn't seem to capture the output, what happens to the output then?

Comment: It is not displayed on the screen nor is it sent to the file. I assumed that using `program &>> file` would address it, but also didn't add anything to log.

Answer (score 1):

With `expect`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect

package require Tcl 8.5

proc time_to_die {sid} {
    close $sid
    # if close is insufficient (e.g. the program is badly behaved) may
    # need to instead get and blast away at the pid
    #set pid [exp_pid $sid]
    #exec kill $pid
    exit
}

# spam output to this here file
log_file log

spawn -noecho TODOyourprogramhereFIXME

# and this here is in milliseconds
after 10000 [list time_to_die $spawn_id]

vwait godot
```

Which should run the program in a PTY, collect its output via the `log_file` call, and after 10 seconds close it. If there is distinctive output that happens before the 10 seconds are up, one could instead detect that and close-or-kill the program when that happens with a more typical `expect` detection of program output.